# Recursive Maximum Subarray not returning correct value

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

[image]
I am trying to solve this problem where I am given an array, and I'm supposed to find the biggest difference where the larger number comes after the smaller. For example, if I have the array:

`[100, 113, 110, 85, 105, 102, 86, 63, 81, 101, 94, 106, 101, 79, 94, 90, 97]`

Then the output should be `(7, 11, 43)` where `7` is the starting index (value 63) and `11` is the ending index (value 106) and `43` is the difference/profit.

However, the output Im getting is `(0, 16, 1607)`.

There are several threads of similar problems but unfortunately I need to stick very closely to the pseudo code below, and so I was unable to find something helpful.

[image]

[image]

This is the code I have so far. Not really sure why its giving me the wrong output. NOTE that the pseudo code is 1 index based i.e. it starts from index 1 and not 0.

```
def find_max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high):
    max_left = low
    max_right = high
    left_sum = -math.inf
    sum = 0
    for i in reversed(range(low, mid)):
        sum = sum + A[i]
        if sum > left_sum:
            left_sum = sum
            max_left = i

    right_sum = -math.inf
    sum = 0
    for j in range(mid, high):
        sum = sum + A[j]
        if sum > right_sum:
            right_sum = sum
            max_right = j
    return (max_left, max_right, left_sum + right_sum)


def find_maximum_subarray(A, low, high):
    if low + 1 == high:
        return (low, high, A[low])
    else:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        (left_low, left_high, left_sum) = find_maximum_subarray(A, low, mid)
        (right_low, right_high, right_sum) = find_maximum_subarray(A, mid, high)
        (cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum) = find_max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high)
        if left_sum >= right_sum and left_sum >= cross_sum:
            return (left_low, left_high, left_sum)
        elif right_sum >= left_sum and right_sum >= cross_sum:
            return (right_low, right_high, right_sum)
        else:
            return (cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum)

bf = find_maximum_subarray(array, 0, len(array))
print(bf)
```

Comment: It looks like it's just returning the sum of the entire array

Comment: Value 106 is at index 11.

Comment: The pseudo-code you've posted is for the maximum subarray sum problem, which is completely unrelated to the problem in the question.

Comment: you are sending the length of the array as high.  This makes no sense.

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry I fixed it. This is the pseudo code I have been provided so yeah im not sure. I added the problem description as well.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain how this problem is related to `maximum-subarray` problem? What is the intuition?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just do this?

```
def min_max_diff(x):
   def process(x):
       y = sorted(x)
       min = y[0]
       max = sorted(x[x.index(min):])[-1]
       return min, max
    while x:
        min, max = process(x)
        if max <= min:
            x.remove(min)
            min, max = process(x)
        else:
            break
    return min, max, max-min

x = [100, 113, 110, 85, 105, 102, 86, 63, 81, 101, 94, 106, 101, 79, 94, 90, 97]
result = min_max_diff(x)
print(result)
```

Comment: Definitely doesn't work if the smallest element of the array is the last element of the array.

Comment: Nothing would work if the elements were in sequential order from largest to smallest

Comment: Example: [2,3,1]

Comment: Updated to support this condition

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Perhaps, but as mentioned I have to follow the pseudo code as closely as possible. Yeah I know it sucks..

Comment: Your psuedo code makes no sense. First what is the point of getting the average?  Second why are you summing each element if you just want the difference between the highest and lowest?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Its not my pseudo code. My teacher gave me this pseudo code and that problem description.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using a single pass over the given array, and you do not need to calculate the maximum-subarray for this problem. May be the problem statement and maximum-subarray are two different problem.

It is clearly mentioned that, you are only allowed to buy a single stock and sell it in a later date. So, the intuition is:

- We always try to lower the buying price
- For every possible buying price, we will try to maximize the profit by selling it to a higher possible future price.

The following C++ code solves the problem:

```
    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {
        int sz = prices.size();
        if(sz < 2) return 0;
        int mxProfit = -INT_MAX, minPrice = prices[0];
        
        for(int i=0; i<sz; i+=1) {
            mxProfit = max(mxProfit, prices[i] - minPrice);
            minPrice = min(minPrice, prices[i]);
        }
        
        return mxProfit;
    }
```